# Using fn in Array.prototype.apply without thisargument?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at a tutorial and why can you call Array.prototype.pop.apply or call without the thisArg specified?   Notice difference in line 1 and 3 in calculation expression.

for example:

```
    var calculate = function () {
        var fn = Array.prototype.pop.apply(arguments);
        console.log(fn);
        return fn.apply(null, arguments);

    };

    var sum = function (x, y) {
        return x + y;
    };

    var diff = function (x, y) {
        return x - y;
    }


    var x = calculate(5, 3, sum);
```

If i do this, I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.pop called on null or undefined Default.aspx:54 (anonymous function)

```
  var fn = Array.prototype.pop.apply(null, arguments);
```

Comment: You want to call `pop` on arguments like `arguments.pop` , that means the `this` is arguments. So it should be `Array.prototype.pop.apply(arguments);`

Answer (score 1):

Array.prototype.pop is called on an array and doesn't take arguments normally:

`[1, 2, 3, 4].pop() //=> 4`

Pop is a method on an instance of Array, and so it uses "this" explicitly. It probably has some internal definition like this terrible approximation:

```
Array.prototype.pop = function() {
   var value = this[this.length - 1];
   delete this[this.length - 1];
   return value;
}
```

So when you call `pop` with a `this` that is null, it has nothing to access for information, the arguments are never used. As [was said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102024/using-fn-in-array-prototype-apply-without-thisargument#comment31746416_21102024) the `arguments` list *is* the `this` in this case. You are effectively calling `arguments.pop()` but arguments doesn't actually have a pop method so you are applying the `Array.prototype.pop` method on it.

Comment: thank you, your explanation was good, array is a speical case that has the argumments as the this argument. i'll have to get my brain to wrap around it